# What is the equivalent of DirectCast in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my sample VB.NET code that uses [`DirectCast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/directcast-operator). I am having trouble converting it to C#.

```vb
Dim arr As ArrayList
If ViewState("SelectedRecords") IsNot Nothing Then
    arr = DirectCast(ViewState("SelectedRecords"), ArrayList)
Else
    arr = New ArrayList()
End If
```

Comment: You tried a cast in C# and it didn’t work?

Comment: yeah, I tried to use DirectCast function in c# but it does not work.

Comment: Is the solution not simply `(ArrayList)ViewState("SelectedRecords")`?

Comment: It’s not a function; it’s an operator. The equivalent in C# is a cast. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions

Comment: I tried that, john, but it does not work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equivalent C# code is

```
ArrayList arr = default(ArrayList);
if (ViewState["SelectedRecords"] != null) {
    arr = (ArrayList)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
}
else {
    arr = new ArrayList();
}
```